# spark web UI notations

Tags: apache-spark

I am running the sample job on my end and the spark job UI says the total uptime is 26 sec but when i add up the duration column for jobs it is only around 17-18 sec .Which one should i rely on in order to determine the total time to run the execution logic of my job .I am not concerned about the time ot takes to start and stop the cluster .Is 26 sec including that time ,is thats the case how do i ignore the time to start the and stop the cluster and get the final execution time for my logic .

[Spark job UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi7IB.png)

Also my spark configuration looks like this :

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Metrics").setMaster("spark://master:7077").set("spark.executor.memory", "5g").set("spark.cores.max", "4").set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse")set("spark.executor.memory", "5g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

I have 2 physical core and 2 virtual core machine i.e 4 logical core .I am trying to use all the core by setting it to 4 core in the configuration but for some reason only 1 executor is used to run the job .Can somebody explain me the reason as to why only 1 executor is spawned and what is the relation between a core and the executor in the spark world .I am new to spark so any help would be great.

[Executor for the job here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnKyt.png)

Answer (score 0):

A single executor can use multiple threads like in your case. You have one executor with 4 cores.

Each executor thread can process a single partition at the time so your cluster can process four partitions concurrently.

In a small setup like this there is no reason to start multiple executor JVM but if you can use `spark.executor.cores` to configure how many cores a single executor can use.

Comment: thanks for the explaination ,do you have an idea about the first query as to why spark web ui shows 26 sec in the uptime vs 15 sec  in the duration column.